# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I´m working with my project in Local and Probe Server and it does work fine! But in Production Server I cant use post method. I have realized this little example to try find the Error.

Controller

```
class PruebaControladorController extends Controller {
  public function holamundo() {

    return view('holamundo');
  }
  public function holamundopost() {

    dd('Hola Mundo POST');
  }
}
```

View

```
Formulario<br>

<form action="{{ url('mandadatos') }}" method="POST" id="signin-form_id" >
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    campo : <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Routes File

```
Route::get('entrada', 'PruebaControladorController@holamundo');
Route::post('mandadatos', 'PruebaControladorController@holamundopost');
```

I can acces to GET Method but POST Method launch this error.

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So it works on your local but not in production? Have you deployed the code and made sure routes are not cached `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: I only have FTP in production Server, but i have detected with path Complete in action value the example it does work!!! I need configure the path that uses url function, Someone know how can configurar it?. TKs Seva Kalashnikov for your Answer.